# Search sales orders filtered by customer using suitescript

Tags: suitescript

I need to retrieve all sales orders for a specific customer ( using customer internal id ). I can find documentation on how to perform this in SuiteTalk, but SuiteTalk's performance is abysmal and am transitioning to SuiteScript/RESTlets.

SuiteScript v1 is available for me to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this question, I've found the solution to be:

```js
var salesorderSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("salesorder",null,
[
    ["customer.internalid", "anyof", param.id],
    "AND",
    ["type", "anyof", "SalesOrd"],
],
[
    new nlobjSearchColumn("internalid"),
]
);
```

where `param.id` is equal to the internal ID of the customer.